# PLSQL: How to insert data in GTT using view inside an SP

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to insert data in a temp table(my_temp_table) using View(VWBLKDATA) as follows but getting compilation error "Error(7,15): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist". However i am able to successfully execute view separately.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE InsrtInTemp
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO my_temp_table SELECT * FROM VWBLKDATA;
  COMMIT;
END InsrtInTemp;
```

But when i am writing dynamic query as below, it compiles successfully

```
create or replace PROCEDURE InsrtInTemp
AS
intrtmp VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  intrtmp := 'INSERT INTO my_temp_table SELECT * FROM VWBLKDATA';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE intrtmp;
END InsrtInTemp;
```

Please help me understanding this behavior.

Comment: An Oracle temporary table is (or should be) created once and is visible to everyone.  In `INSERT INTO` statement won't create a temporary table.  It looks like your temporary table does not exist yet when you compile the procedure.  You'd need to do the `CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE` first.  I'm guessing that you are coming from a different database (SQL Server, MySQL, etc) where temporary tables are much more common and where temporary tables are visible only to the current session.  Oracle is a very different animal and temporary tables are very uncommon.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JustinCave , very clear explanation. Yes, i have worked on SQL SERVER and new to PLSQL. Thanks again.